# Bounding $F(x) =\int_{1+x}^{\exp(x)}\dfrac{1}{\ln(t)}dt$

Tags: integration

We Suppose $\forall x> 0$ the function $F$ defined as:

$F(x) =\int_{1+x}^{\exp(x)}\dfrac{1}{\ln(t)}dt $.

How can I prove that:
$\forall x>0 \quad \dfrac{\exp(x)-1-x}{x}\le F(x)\le \dfrac{exp(x)-1-x}{\ln(1+x)}$

**P.S:Without using such advanced ways like the property of the convolution or something like that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the minimum and $M$ the maximum of a say continuous function $g(x)$ over the interval $[a,b]$. Then
$$m(b-a)\le \int_a^b g(x)\,dx\le (b-a)M.$$

That's **exactly** what was used to derive the inequalities you are concerned about. On your interval, $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is smallest at $e^x$, and biggest at $x+1$.

**Remark:** Informally, the inequalities stated above  say that the area under the curve $y=g(x)$ is $\ge$ the area of a certain rectangle and $\le$ the area of a certain rectangle. So the inequalities are geometrically obvious. They can be proved formally, if necessary, from the definition of Riemann integral. In this problem, you would probably not be expected to *prove* the inequalities above. *Using*  them is enough.